# Iphone displaying wordpress site wrong

Tags: iphone, wordpress, mobile-safari

So I have a wordpress site I have been working on displaying fine in web broswers.

Here's the site. [xs sailing](http://www.xsracing.org/test2/)

When it loads on the iphone it looks like the picture attached. There is nothing to the left and I cannot scroll left at all.
[Picture of site on iphone](http://www.xsracing.org/test2/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/photo.png)

any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you don't even have the needed iDevices tags, so Mobile Safari will make assumptions and maybe it's having some wrong ones.

you should set some values on your code to make all go nice and well.

let's start with the [`viewport`](http://chriscoyier.net/2009/01/25/iphone-meta-tag-for-viewport-maintaining-scale-on-orientation-change/)

```
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

and then, you have a [**bunch of meta tags**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-web-app-meta-tags/) to play with

---

**Plus** you [should ALWAYS validate your site](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.xsracing.org/test2/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)... don't expect that everything will run smooth if you have more than **1100** validation errors! There's even opened tags without their close tag...